# wsHttpBinding with custom autorization, certificates authentification and message transfersecurity

Tags: c#, wcf

I need some help with WCF!

I wrote WCF-service with custom authorization and authentication. Service works well when I start it from Visual Studio, but when I start it from any host (Windows Service or Host that was created by me) - throws next exception:

*"An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail."*

The inner exception:

*"An error occurred when verifying security for the message."*

Service config (it config i copied to host app.cong):

```xml
<system.serviceModel>

    <!--Binding with custom authentication-->
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="licenseServiceBinding">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="NS_SLM_Service.Service.LicenseService" behaviorConfiguration="customBehaviour">

        <!--One service devided by a few contracts, because on a client need to separate API-functions-->

        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="licenseServiceBinding" contract="NS_SLM_Service.Service.IAdminFunctions" />

        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="licenseServiceBinding" contract="NS_SLM_Service.Service.IManagerFunctions" />

        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/LicenseService/CommonFunctions" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="NS_SLM_Service.Service.ICommonFunctions" />

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/LicenseService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="customBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />

          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom">
            <authorizationPolicies>
              <add policyType="NS_SLM_Service.UserAuthorization,NS_SLM_Service" />
            </authorizationPolicies>
          </serviceAuthorization>

          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="NS_SLM_Service.UserAuthentication,NS_SLM_Service" />
            <serviceCertificate findValue="tempCert" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeName="My" />
          </serviceCredentials>

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Next code trying to connect to this service:

```cs
using (var proxy = new MyService())
                {
                    proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Login";
                    proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

                    proxy.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

                    proxy.SomeMethod("Parametr");
                }
```

I frustrated because when I try to connect to service when it launced in VS, I don`t see any exeptions ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you inner exception message is not very precise I would start investigation from enabling wcf logging which will produce detailed information about what exactly went wrong.

You can find example configuration here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

For browsing logs you can use SvcTraceViewer.exe tool from SDK.